# Efficiently Combine MatchCollections in .NET regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex, ienumerable

In the simplified example, there are two regular expressions, one case sensitive, the other not. The idea would be to **efficiently** create an IEnumerable collection (see "combined" below) combining the results.

```
string test = "abcABC";
string regex = "(?<grpa>a)|(?<grpb>b)|(?<grpc>c)]";
Regex regNoCase = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex regCase = new Regex(regex);

MatchCollection matchNoCase = regNoCase.Matches(test);
MatchCollection matchCase = regCase.Matches(test);

// Combine matchNoCase and matchCase into an IEnumerable
IEnumerable<Match> combined = null;
foreach (Match match in combined)
{
    // Use the Index and (successful) Groups properties
    //of the match in another operation

}
```

In practice, the MatchCollections might contain thousands of results and be run frequently using long dynamically created regular expressions, so I'd like to shy away from copying the results to arrays, etc. I am still learning LINQ and am fuzzy on how to go about combining these or what the performance hits to an already sluggish process will be.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are three steps here:

1. Convert the `MatchCollection`'s to `IEnumerable<Match>`'s
2. Concatenate the sequences
3. Filter by whether the `Match.Success` property is true

Code:

```
IEnumerable<Match> combined = matchNoCase.OfType<Match>().Concat(matchCase.OfType<Match>()).Where(m => m.Success);
```

Doing this creates a new enumerator which only executes each step as the next result is fetched, so you only end up enumerating through each collection once, total. For example, [Concat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) will only start executing the second enumerator after the first runs out.

Comment: I think .Concat() might be better than .Union() here, unless you are intentionally wanting to avoid overlap in results.

Answer (score 0):

The answer marked correct creates an IEnumerable with two of each match.  The correct way to combine is below:

```
var combined = matches.Where(e=>e.Success).Select(e=>e.Value);
```

Comment: OP suggested efficiency. While LINQ does not necessarily mean not efficient, there is always going to be a more efficient way than using LINQ, as it adds an extra layer on top. It helps with code brevity, but not efficiency or performance, instead actually creates more overhead.