# Combine two MatchCollection and overwrite if index of the value is same

Tags: c#, regex, collections, match, string-matching

I have two `MatchCollection` `mc` and `SCR`. Suppose both capture 2 and 4 values respectively. (SCR being the superset).
Example

```
mc
----------------------
capture    index        value
  1         1234         abc
  2         2345         cde
```

and

```
SCR
---------------------
 capture  index        value
    1     1234         abc
    2     1233         abc
    3     2345         cde
    4     1213         cde
```

you can see that SCR is superset and it contain each index that is in mc. I want to update my SCR MatchCollection such that

```
//pseudo code
if mc.index == SCR.index
then update SCR.value = mc.value
```

I tried following answer but still not helping

[Reference Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2917481/2343086)

my own code look like this:

```
foreach (Match a in mc)
                {
                    foreach (Match b in SCR)
                    {
                        if(b.Index==a.Index)
                        {
                            b.Value = a.Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

but value is read only so does not work 
please note that this is what i mean by Match Collection:

```
 MatchCollection mc= Regex.Matches(inFile,pat);
```

Comment: `Match` is immutable. that means you can not change it.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: Combine two collections group them and take the first group. Something like MatchCollection result = new List<MatchCollection> { mc, scr }
                .SelectMany(x => x)
                .GroupBy(item => item.Index)
                .Select(g => g.First());

Comment: simply did by writing to db and updating result there, besides easiest way is for sure to convert to List @Lepijohnny